# Wildcard subdomains and rewrite rules generate php log error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I hope you help me, I describe the situation:

wildcard subdomains root folder: _wildcard_ncc

in _wildcard_ncc there are index.php, .htaccess and site folder with all website files

if I open for example test.domain.com or test2.domain.com everything works fine, no errors showed, but on the server I have the log... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'site' not found in /home/nccone/public_html/_wildcard_ncc/site/libs/Bootstrap.php:25

Class site doesn't exists in my controllers and never call it, site is the name of the files folder.

If I remove rewrite rules from .htaccess problem disappear but I cannot use the site without mod rewrite

.htaccess code

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    Options -Indexes
```

Can anyone help me? I'm not an htaccess expert. Thanks or

Comment: This is a PHP error. Update your question with all relevant code.

Comment: The error is telling you where the issue is. Check the file `site/libs/Bootstrap.php`, line 25 is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem... missing favicon.ico in the wildcard subdomain root folder generated the error! PHP was OK! I don't know why